# Is there any way to create elevation mesh plot in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop

I am using ArcMap 10.1.  I have data with elevation value. Now I want to create mesh plot (as created in Golden Software Surfer).

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean what I would call a 'wireline' (see image below), there is no direct analogy in ArcGIS, which has long been a failing in my opinion.  However, you can approximate it (though the results aren't fantastic).

[image]

You will need 3D Analyst extension and need to convert your DTM to a TIN and then adjust the display to show the edges and set all the faces to white.  Obviously this does not give a nice regular mesh and you don't get 3D axes. It is far from perfect!

If you need a regular grid, you could create a [fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002q000000) at the resolution of your DTM (or less if that is too 'crowded' and drape it over your DTM in ArcScene.  Then hide the DTM or better, set it to be entirely white so you can't see through your mesh (which is just confusing).

The above is still not great.  If you don't mind switching tools, you could use GRASS (which is free).  I have done similar plots in NVIZ though, again, they are not entirely ideal.

I mostly use wireline images as part of a visibility analysis, so I tend to need a 'zoomed in' view where the viewer is 'in' the terrain (i.e. no axes at all).  For this I mostly use proprietary Wind Farm software or a 3D modelling package like Blender (with the latter I could generate 3D axes, but so far I've not got around to writing a script to do that).

So, I realise that this answer will be disappointing but I hope it helps a bit anyway.

Comment: what a lack of gis giant!!!!!